# Where SQL Clause statement for selecting passed date time Codeigniter Active record

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a database schema like this:

```
sms_queue
---------------
id
status
Date Time
```

How do I arrange codeigniter active record to update the **status** only for the passed day (date time) the reference time is the time when I call the function?

Let say according to my time zone, it is on 11-01-14 (11th january 2014), and i have 5 tuple.

```
sms_queue
+----+--------+----------------+
| id | status | Date Time      |
+====+========+================+
| 1  | unsent | 15-01-14 18:45 |
| 2  | unsent | 02-01-14 08:15 |
| 3  | unsent | 01-01-14 07:00 |
| 4  | unsent | 11-01-14 09:00 |
| 5  | unsent | 13-01-14 07:00 | 
+----+--------+----------------+
```

what where clause on active record / sql statement should i use to select only for the second and third data above assuming today is 11-01-14

i mean the query must be **like this**

```
$this->db->where(blablabla)
         ->update('sms_queue',array('status'=>'sent'))
```

so what is the `blablabla`

i hope the answer is using active record not a sql statement since it says that using codeigniter active record is more safer for security issue.

Comment: i can't understand your question clearly, do you want to update your row status?

Comment: @MajidGolshadi see it again sorry for my bad english

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You want "passed day", so 24 hours from current time or entire day?. Your example is 11-01-14, the only record within 1 day of that is `id 4`, so can you explain why only `id 2 and 3` should be returned?

Comment: @ConnorTumbleson yes i mean that. sorry for my bad english

Comment: What's the type and (if not datetime/timestamp) actual value of `Date Time`?  The shown data is not nicely sortable/searchable - please always post in ISO Standard.  What do you want the table to look like when you're done?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Date Time in 'YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss' format not timestamp format.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i could answer my own question and found the solution for my specific problem.

i use this one

```
$this->db->where('Date time <',date(Y-m-d))
         ->update('sms_queue',array('status'=>'sent'));
```

The query will update the status to be `sent` for every item who have the date time on the past day of today.

Sorry if my question is not so clear. Sorry for my bad english.